# Mysql+php, how to make a link that shows all data from a record when you press the "headline"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

As the title says, and this is not probably a question, more a hint how to do it.

I have table with four fields, **id (auto+primary)**, **firstname**, **lastname**, **age**.

On my index page I select *, then I make the firstname to a link which goes to antoher page which I want to show all data for that record.

For the moment I have to do it manually "select * from " where id="2". (the other page)

How do I make the link to autodetect "the id from that record set" and only display data from that record.

You can see my curreny project here,

http://www.adamskymotorkylare.se/business/

as you can see, when you click the "firstname" it will always display data where id=2 ( paris hilton ), what I want it to do, it when I click "jack" it will select * from where id="1"

Thanks in advance, Jack

"index page"

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM persons");

echo "<table width=100%>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Gender</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$id = $row['id'];

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] .  "</td>";
echo "<td> <a href='view_more.php?id= . $id .'>" . $row['firstname'] . "</a> </td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] .  "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

"viewmore page"

```
$id = $_get['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM persons 
WHERE id='$id'");

echo "<table width=100%>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Gender</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> <a href='#'>" . $row['firstname'] . "</a> </td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] .  "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, on your page that indexes the users:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$id = $row['id'];
$firstName = $row['firstName'];

echo ('<a href="user_account.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $firstName . '</a>');
}
```

This means if someone clicks the first name they will be sent to user_account.php (can replace this obviously) and you will pass in the ID via the URL (user_account.php?id=123).

On the User Account page you want to do the following:

```
// GET ID FROM THE URL

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT (WHATEVER YOU WANT) FROM (YOUR TABLE) WHERE id = $id");
```

Notes:
Replace variables and query with the details you need.

I hope that goes some way to helping.

Comment: this is exaclty what I am looking for, but I am doing something wrong, the url field view something else and not the id ;/

Comment: Can you copy your PHP here, and we can take a look, if you edit your original question with the current PHP from the index page, and then the view user page we can see where you are having difficulty.

Comment: echo "<td> <a href='view_more.php?id=" . $id . " '>" . $row['firstname'] . "</a> </td>";

Comment: That should do it. When you concatenate in PHP if some of it is text you need to make sure you end that with whichever method you started with, in this case you used " then use your . $variable . then reopen " and close again at the end.

Comment: you're right, it did the magic, but there is one more problem, the view more page doesn't seems to get the id, hmm

Comment: $id = $_GET['id'];

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM persons 
WHERE id = $id");

Comment: Try that, and if that's not working, try:

$id = $_GET['id'];

echo $id;

Comment: I should have explained GET needs to be in Caps.

Comment: To people reading this answer, please make sure to actually use parameterized queries, as this answer is susceptible to sql injection. Alternatively, if @DanDotNet ever comes back, maybe consider updating this code with parameterized query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="./view_more.php?id=$id">UserFirstName</a>
```

$id is user record id first column of your table so when you send it to view_more.php page you can get clicked id $_GET['id']; and get user records for that id and link is user name

and $id you get form data base the way you get first name

Comment: updated  and your page is looking good you just need to add $id in link to do get method

Comment: I am still not sure how to specifi the select * from id in the detail page, hmm

Comment: and it does seems to get an id in the url field

Comment: $_GET['id'] will give you your id for your view_more page in current situation its hard coded to 2 but then $_GET['id'] will be your id

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<?php 
$sql =mysql_query("select * from `table`");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>

    <?php $id = $row['id']; ?>

<a href="detail.php?cid=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo ucwords($row['Firstname']); ?></a>

<?php 
    }
?>
```

on index.php anchor tag will send the user id to detail.php

detail.php

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['cid'];
$sql =mysql_query("select * from `table` where id='".$id."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name:</th>
        <th>Last Name:</th>
        <th>Age Name:</th>
        <th>Gender:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['firstname']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['lastname']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['age']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['gender']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

on `detail.php` `$id` get the user id from index.php. After that id helps in query and while loop which is get and show the user data from database.

Comment: thanks for your respond, I added my current project code in the orginal post, let me now what I have to edit ;)